# Yellow Strip in PNG output with imagemagik with PHP

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

Im using Imagemagik with PHP to convert EPS files into PNGs, everything is fine, for some images it is leaving an yellow strip on the image, may be the background image by defaut but not sure[image]

See this image there you can find yellow color strip at the end, I dont want this to appear, please let me know is there any way to workaround to get over this.

Comment: Do you really think that you have posted enough information for people to help you? http://www.sscce.org/